# s:url tag in struts 2 display url only

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts2, tags

I need to give path of swf file in javascript function. I know s:url tag works for stylesheet and script sources. I however need just

`https://blah.blah.com/portal/blah/blah/MyWebApp/js/myscript.swf`

if i use just `<s:url value="/js/myscript.swf" />`

i get

/myWebApp/js/myscript.swf

Comment: Struts2 tag documentation is your friend: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/url.html the forceAddSchemeHostAndPort and includeContext will interest you.

Comment: dang, I was just about to answer with that, but now it feels wrong... :-)

Comment: @Quaternion you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Struts2 tag documentation is your friend: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4.1/docs/url.html the *forceAddSchemeHostAndPort* and *includeContext* will interest you.